# Будет ли работать данный способ рассылки ВК?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, оптимизация

Взял код из интернета, немного подредактировал, но всё равно боюсь, что при большом количестве бесед рассылка не сработает как надо, поэтому спрашиваю у опытных сработает ли это и можно ли как-нибудь оптимизировать код?

```
for($i = 0; $i < PHP_INT_MAX; $i++) {
    $request_params = array(
        'offset' => ($i * 200),
        'count' => 200,
        'access_token' => VK_TOKEN_GROUP,
        'v' => '5.131'
    );
    // Получаю список диалогов
    $ss = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getConversations?'. http_build_query($request_params));
    $ss = json_decode($ss, true);
    
    
    for($is = 0; $is < $ss['response']['count']; $is++) {
        $request_params = array(
            'message' => $mailing_text,
            'user_id' => $ss['response']['items'][$is]['conversation']['peer']['id'],
            'random_id' => 0,
            'access_token' => VK_TOKEN_GROUP,
            'v' => '5.131'
        );
        // Отправляю рассылку
        json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. http_build_query($request_params)));
        usleep(52000);  // Лимит запросов для ключа сообщества 20 в секунду, взял с запасом
    }
    // Если в последнем запросе меньше 200 диалогов, ломаю цикл
    if ($ss['response']['count'] < 200) break;
}
```

Comment: `usleep = 0,052` секунды (вроде как) + `'count' => 200,` и так забирает до 200 сообщений) + не понятно зачем `json_decode` при отправке.. если результат не важен, есть `file_put_contents` а в целом почему бы и нет

Comment: @Jour не понял на счёт usleep, count => 200 это ограничение вк, так что приходится отбирать по 200 сообщение

Comment: Вы получаете `'count' => 200` - количество сообщений за раз, с шагом `'offset' => ($i * 200)`, а `usleep = 0,052` ваша задержка при отправке сообщений на сервер, если так и надо, то все ок..

Comment: @Jour так и надо, спасибо